# Regex match repeating pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match e-mails with a string like:

```
s.te.e.ve.s.mit.h.p@gmail.com
```

Effectively I'm after any repeating pattern (of at least 4 times) of a string of characters followed by a period, with the last before the email domain not having a period.

I'm not great with Regex, but so far I've only come up with:

```
[aA-zZ\.]{4,}[aA-zZ]@.*
```

This matches what I need, however it also pulls more than I'd like.

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe `^(?:[a-zA-Z]*\.){4}[a-zA-Z.]*@.*`? See https://regex101.com/r/Dx8yDg/1

Comment: Or `(?:[A-Za-z]+\.*){4,}@.*` https://regex101.com/r/rGL0ml/2

Comment: @G.Dimov When you quantify `\.` with `*`, you remove the requirement that there must be dots in the string.

Comment: `[aA-zZ]` is a dangerous thing, it will match `[\]^_\`` too. The correct form is mentioned in above comments!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help, I see now where I was making the mistake.  Wiktor's answer seemed to work the best, though for some reason it would time out in Redshift if I didn't put . in brackets.  [.]

The expression which appears to work correctly is:

^([a-zA-Z]*[.]){4,}[a-zA-Z]*@.*

Comment: Correct.  I was looking to match text separated by at least 4 periods, but not at the end.  So there will be at least 5 groups of text separated by 4 periods.